# They don't like my videos vs None of them like my videos. - What is the difference?

Tags: meaning

Let's say there are three people. Their names are A, B, and C.

**Example 1**

> None of them like my videos.

**Example 2**

> They don't like my videos.

What is the difference?

Comment: What's the context?

Comment: Note also that "liking a video" can mean "enjoying the video" or "clicking the like button on a video". Not clicking the like button doesn't mean you didn't enjoy it, so "None of them liked" means very different things in the two cases.

Answer (score 16):

The difference is subtle but exists.  The difference is whether you are treating A, B, and C as a group with a single group identity, or whether you are treating A, B, and C as separate distinct people unrelated to each other but who happen to share the same opinion for different personal reasons.

> None of them like my videos.

When you look at each element of "them", **none** were found to like your videos.  "None of them" emphasizes the individuality of each of "them", as to determine "none" you have to look at each element by itself.

> They don't like my videos.

**They** is grammatically treated as a single unit.  "They" act together, and share a trait, that trait being the lack of liking your videos.  They are a group, and are thought of as a group.

Comment: The distinction becomes more important when there are a large number of people in the group. You might use "they" to refer to a concensus that doesn't necessarily apply to every single individual. But "none of them" and "all of them" are absolute (although sometimes might be an exaggeration).

Comment: _They_ isn’t treated as a single unit **grammatically**, but **semantically** or **notionally**. I don’t think ‘single unit’ is an actually defined entity within grammar; the closest we get grammatically is _singular_, which _they_ definitely isn’t.

Answer (score 5):

[Richard’s answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/338146/6120) is reasonable, but I think it suggests more attention to precise quantities than the typical speaker would give. The speaker does not need to examine *every* individual’s response before saying that “none of them like my videos”. And they would not need proof that the group has come to a consensus before saying “they don’t like my videos”.

So if the difference is not about the exact numbers, what is it? I propose that it is about **expectations**. How many people did I expect (hope) would like my videos?

Roughly speaking…

- “They don’t like my videos”: I hoped for a generally positive opinion, from the majority of the group.
- “None of them like my videos”: I hoped for *some* positive opinion, from at least one member of the group.

In more detail…

“They don’t like my videos” reports the general opinion of the group (or what the speaker believes the general opinion is). The speaker would do this if the general opinion is what matters most to them. This is probably because they expected the group to express a general opinion; they hoped for a good opinion, or maybe they dreaded a bad opinion.

“None of them like my videos” reports individual opinions of the group members, with the emphasis being that *not even one* person had a good opinion. This might be exaggerated (the speaker might not have talked to everyone), but it shows that the speaker’s expectation (or hope) was that *at least* one person, or a small number of people, would have a good opinion.

Comment: Exactly, it's matter of precision.

Comment: As well as the speaker's expectations of the group, it's also their plain knowledge. Eg if all you know is that a panel overall rejected you vs knowing somehow that each panel member dislikes you.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at it is to say that "None of them" is a more emphatic version. To say, "they didn't like my video" suggests a sort of group consensus which might (or might not) be somewhat diffuse. It's the sort of conclusion you might reach if nobody expressed enthusiasm.
To say, "None of them liked my video" suggests that every single member of the group specifically stated that they did not like it, which is a considerably stronger statement.

Comment: i.e. "none of them" implies "not even one of them", which is a stronger statement.